# How much salt do I use to ferment 1 quart of cabbage?

Tags: salt, fermentation

How much salt do I add to ferment 1 quart of cabbage?

Comment: Right you are, @AndyGiesler ..and you get much more accurate ratios by weight. A quart of cabbage is a highly variable thing (before shredding, after shredding, but before salting, and after salting are wildly different volumes just in the course of making saeurkraut, for the same weight of cabbage.)

Comment: **Do not specify volume**, [edit] your question and give us the weight of that quarter cabbage. How else can we know how large it is, you are not even telling use what kind of cabbage. Voted to close as unclear.

Answer (score 0):

According to the batch of sauerkraut I made yesterday, and this recipe 3/4ths of a Tablespoon per quart of grated cabbage is sufficient to ward off infection without making the end result overly salty.
 http://www.thekitchn.com/how-to-make-homemade-sauerkraut-in-a-mason-jar-193124